# Custom dlls not found in SQL Server 2016 agent job

Tags: sql-server, dll, ssis, sql-server-2016, sql-agent-job

I have an ssis package in SQL Server 2016 which is using a custom dll that I have added in the gac. SSIS package works fine in visual studio but when I deploy it on SQL Server, it can not find the dll frm gac.

Can anyone help me where to place that custom dll?

I've added exception handling in my task script and saving the logs in a text file which says

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'abc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> File name: 'abc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>
> at ST_7a052dcdad9e4fe18bb49852****.Job.runTask()
>   at ST_7a052dcdad9e4fe18bb49852****.ScriptMain.Main()
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
>
> Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Comment: Did you also deploy the DLL to the GAC on the production server?

Comment: yes i did, using gacutil

Comment: Have u try to list out all GAC file with Cmd?

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 possible causes:

1. **32/64 bit conflict:** Make sure that the mode you are running with is relevant to the dll version. Try running the package in 32-bit mode in SQL job:

   - [Running SSIS Packages in 32-bit](https://www.sqlhammer.com/running-ssis-packages-in-32-bit/)
2. Copy the registered dll to the SQL assemblies path: `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\<SQL Version>\SDK\Assemblies` and then register it to GAC. Also make sure that this is the path referenced in the package

**Workaround**

Using the AssemblyResolve Function:

- [How to avoid manually browsing DLL in Add Reference of Script Task when deploying package on production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055268/how-to-avoid-manually-browsing-dll-in-add-reference-of-script-task-when-deployin)

Comment: It didn't work so in the end i had to call executable in task script instead of using dll.